# Success function doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to delete image box with ajax, my `class="box"` doesn't disappear when i click delete but my image has been deleted from database and unlink from folder, can anyone see if somethings wrong with my code, thanks in advance!

My code :

```
<ul>
<?php while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>
    <li class="box">
        <div class="image-box">
            <div class="items-image" style="background-image: url(upload/<?php echo $result['img_1']; ?>);"></div>
            <p class="error" style="display: none;">Can't delete</p>
            <div class="items-footer">
                <a class="delete" id="<?php echo $result['img_id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete").on('click', function(evt){
    var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var prop_id = "<?php echo $ID; ?>";
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'image_delete.php',
            data: ({delete_id : del_id, product_id: prop_id}),
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == '0') {
                    $(".error").show();
                } else if(data == '1') {
                    $(this).parents(".box").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

image_upload.php

```
<?php 
include 'connect.php';
$path = "upload/";
if(isset($_POST['delete_id'])){
    $delete_id = $_POST['delete_id'];
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(img_id) as cnt FROM fm_product_image WHERE p_id_img = '$product_id'") or die(mysql_error());
    $getcheck = mysql_fetch_array($check);

    if($getcheck['cnt'] == '1') {
        echo '0';
    } else {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT img_1 FROM fm_product_image WHERE img_id = '$delete_id'") or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        $delete = $result['img_1'];
        $unlink = $path.$delete;

        if (unlink($unlink)) {
            mysql_query("DELETE fm_product_image FROM fm_product_image WHERE img_id = '$delete_id'") or die(mysql_error());
            echo '1';
        } else {
            echo '0';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use remove:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete").on('click', function(evt){
    var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var prop_id = "<?php echo $ID; ?>";
    var box = $(this).closest(".box");
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'image_delete.php',
            data: ({delete_id : del_id, product_id: prop_id}),
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == '0') {
                    $(".error").show();
                } else if(data == '1') {
                    box.animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow").animate({ opacity: 0 }, "slow");
                    box.remove();
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

note: `$(this)` refers to the ajax object and opacity is a value from 1 to 0

Comment: typo  `var box = .closest(".box");`

Comment: @roullie sorry, fixed;